# Is it correct to say "the margin of differences"?

Tags: meaning

There are some instances of decrease in the average temperature of some place.

I need to cast doubt on the significance of the decrease.

can I say:

> The margin of the differences may not be notable.

Comment: Why not "The *decrease* may be insignificant." ?  Decrease already contains the idea of difference. Margin of difference of decrease is unnecessary.

Comment: The word ***margin*** probably has no place in what you're trying to say. Perhaps you're being influenced by the fact that in your context the *reason* any measured differences may not be significant is because they are *within the **margin** of error* (in reality there may be no difference at all, but the measuring process isn't totally accurate).

Answer (score 1):

The usual language for this sort of thing is to say "the temperature decrease may not be [statistically] significant", or perhaps "the amount of the temperature decrease […]" (Preferably, though, you'd mention the level of significance you're using with something like "at p<0.05", and be able to say that it either is or isn't significant accordingly.)

"Margin" is hard to use in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the two words, **margin and difference** can go together so as to describe or modify each other.

According to definition #5 of **margin** from [American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/margin), margin is a measure, quantity, or degree of difference.

This said it wouldn't be appropriate to say **the difference of differences**.

So you'd rather use either margin or difference.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant *marginal difference*.

"Marginal difference" means the difference at the margin (i.e., the difference in the dependent variable (temperature) corresponding to a unit difference in the dependent variable (a single unit of time)). Compare this to the economic concept of *marginal utility*, the utility gained from consuming one additional unit of a good.

As the other answers suggest, *margin of differences* isn't really meaningful.